# PL/SQL Merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm looking to implement a sort of Type 2 Slow Changing Dimension like behavior into my dimension table using PL/SQL's MERGE statement. It workd just fine for updating existing values and inserting new ones. I'm looking to extend this functionality by not only updating existing values but creating a different row with the updated values while preserving the row with the "outdated" values.

In short, is it possible to do this?

```
MERGE INTO A
USING B
ON (A.ID = B.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE END_DATE ON THE EXISTING ROW;
    INSERT UPDATED VALUES IN A NEW ROW;
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT A NEW ROW WITH NEW VALUES;
```

Thanks you guys in advance.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example, only plain SQL. Please show us the complete stored procedure if you have a question about PL/SQL

Comment: Your syntax could use help. I am no expert on `MERGE`, so I will direct you to the same documentation which I would consult: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm

Comment: You want to do it in one statement (AFAIK, it impossible) or in a several PL/SQL statements?

Comment: Thanks for your response @ Politank-Z. In this case my code is irrelevant because all i have right now is a simple MERGE statement like the one in the documentation you provided. My problem is that i want to extend the functionality of the WHEN MATCHED THEN clause from a simple UPDATE statement to a UPDATE and an INSERT statement (possibly in another table alltogether).

Comment: Hey @Dmitry I was trying to do it all one MERGE statement. If that is not possible i guess i'll have to go with multiple statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly doing  a Type 2 dimension and want to use a merge, yes it can be done but it's not terribly straightforward.  Effectively, if you will need to compare your data using an inline view in the USING clause, that features a column that indicates whether its an insert or an update.  This field gets joined to an slowly changing dimension table that drives whether an insert or an update occurs.

This blog post describes the technique in great detail and has worked for us, albeit we used a hash to determine unqiueness as opposed to a column by column compare.

[Load Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 using Oracle Merge Statement](http://databobjr.blogspot.com/2011/04/load-slowly-changing-dimension-type-2.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it! A big thank you to everyone else who pitched in as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two statements instead of 1 here.

(in your pseudo-code)

```
UPDATE END_DATE IN A WHERE A.ID = something_from_B

INSERT new VALUES IN A
```

The insert needs to happen no matter what. So no need of checking if the row exists or not (and only updating if the row exists). Just end_date all records that match B. This would end_date 0 to n number of rows. And then Insert everything together without worrying if that record has been end-dated already or not.

Put this inside a `BEGIN...END;` if you want transactional atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

In short - no. A MERGE statement provides the option to INSERT if matching data is not found, and to UPDATE if matching data is found. It does NOT give the option to "update-and-insert" if matching data is found.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you wrote a pseudocode. So I can suggest just an idea also in pseudocode:

```
MERGE INTO A
USING (select * from B1 union all 
       select * from B2) B
ON (A.ID = B.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE END_DATE ON THE EXISTING ROW FROM B1;
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT A NEW ROW WITH NEW VALUES FROM B2;
```

If you want to insert updated rows as new, you can generate subquery based on `B`, which will contain "updated rows", but these rows have to be considered as new by SQL engine (it is impossible to say how to do it without details about your tables). In my query `B1` is "rows to update", and `B2` is "updated rows which have to look as new". If you do this, updated rows will be inserted.
Also, no guarantee that in your case it could be implemented.